# Display images via simple comma separated list of URLs

Tags: php, csv

I've never really worked with PHP before and I'm creating an online MySQL database of JPG images. Currently I can only display one image per record with this:

```
$value = '< img src="'.$value.'" width="100%" />';
```

The `$value` field would normally contain one URL, for example `http://www.imagehost.com/image1.jpg`

I'd like to be able to display multiple images per record by comma-separated values.

i.e. `URL1, URL2, URL3`

This would stack three images on top of each other (unless someone can think of a simpler method?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use an array

```
$images = array(
    'url1',
    'url2',
    'url3',
);
```

But it sounds like they are stored in a single db field, so you can use CSV then turn that into an array.

```
$images_csv = 'url1,url2,url3'; // comma separated, not "comma space"
$images = explode(',', $images_csv );

$value = '';
foreach ($images as $im){
    $value .= '<img src="'. $im . '" />';
}
```

Note that if you use `comma space` as in your example, you would need to explode by that, or trim each element.

```
$images_csv = 'url1, url2, url3';
$images = explode(', ', $images_csv );
```

You could also json encode or serialize an array of images, to store them as one string.

Comment: *"unless someone can think of a simpler method?"* But yes there is.

Comment: isnt it about first how to get those values ?

Comment: I'm unable to get that working sadly. I wrote URL1, URL2, URL3 etc. as I don't have the rep to post more than two links.

So I presume  $images_csv = '$value'; would be more appropriate, however that doesn't work either :/

Comment: Then I don't know what the question is.